# Not able to extract Certain field from a document

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-tesseract

[image]I want to extract gross income from Income-tax (a document).Here are the things i have tried.
1)Using Ctpn ,form the countours,and crop those parts,and fed it to pytesseract.But it is giving very bad results.
2) I tried Adaptive thersolding , before feeding to to pytesseract, doesn't helped.
3)The image should be greater than 70 dpi before we are feeding to tesseract , so  I am scalling it too . Additionally i have tried taking average but hard luck.

Can anyone please tell me how can i extract that.[image]

Comment: Could you please post the input image to your algorithm and the ideal output required? It's very difficult for us to help you with the current image you have  posted.

Comment: @Meghana Actually Input image is the same image without countours.

Comment: @Meghana Actually i want to extract gross Total Income ..